# Columns layout by using dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to create a layout with columns by using dompdf. After some research I used `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`

The problem is next:

If I have 2 columns (column1 and column2), column1 will generate on page1 and if column1 exceeds page1 and the content goes on page2, then the next column (column2) will be generated on page2, not on page1 as it should be.

Do you know how to fix this issue with columns in dompdf, or give me an advice how to successfully do this?

UPDATED

I replaced columns with tables. So now I have a table with a row and 3 columns. The problem is this: if the content of one column exceeds the height of current page, then it goes in a very long processing time or it breaks/crush. So this is not working also. Should be a fix for this by using the css tags page-break-* ?

So what is the option if I want to have 3 columns on a page, and a column to have the possibility to break it`s content on the next page also.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in mine as well. Tried many things but didn't workout. Hope someone to figure out soon.

Comment: You can check for replies here. There is not a workaround right now. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1192